# Server error with next auth. reddit provider not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, provider, next-auth

I'm getting a server error with next-auth.  I believe I used [...nextauth].js correctly but it's saying my () after my providers is incorrect.  Finding docs regarding Reddit is tough with next.js

here is the file my error is happening

'TypeError: (0 , next_auth_providers_reddit__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.RedditProvider) is not a function'

[...nextauth].js

```
import { NextAuth } from 'next-auth';
import { RedditProvider } from 'next-auth/providers/reddit';

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        RedditProvider({
            clientId: process.env.REDDIT_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

does anyone see the issue that is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import RedditProvider from "next-auth/providers/reddit"
```

Which version of next-auth are you using. In my case, Reddit provider is a default export so no need for curly braces.

Comment: I am using v4.  I tried your recommendation but got a syntax error with my env providers.  Error: 
  x Expected ',', got ':'
   ,----
 7 | (clientId: process.env.REDDIT_CLIENT_ID),
   :          ^
   `----

Caused by:
    0: failed to process input file
    1: Syntax Error

Comment: This is the offical link: https://next-auth.js.org/providers/reddit#example.
As you can see, there's really no curly braces. Also, I think there's none for NextAuth as well: https://next-auth.js.org/providers/reddit#example. Can you double check the documentation.